# Cómo Recargar datos mysql automaticamente en MaterialDataTable v.10 para angular 10

Tags: angular, api, datatable, observable, material

Buen Día, Adjunto código de un MaterialDataTable que filtra, ordena y pagina con información de un API Rest de laravel, todo funciona bien, pero; **cuando ingreso información directamente en la tabla de la Base de Datos, esta información no se ve reflejada en el MaterialDataTable** sino hasta que manualmente se cambia de URL con el menú de la APP o se refresca la pantalla.
Aunque se este usando *MatTableDataSource* y la documentación indica que las operaciones las hace del lado del cliente, esto no debería ser impedimento para que el servicio este llamando constantemente al get de la API. Se usa Angular: 10.0.11 y Material-Angular: 10.1.3

Por favor si me pueden indicar que debo agregar al código (tal vez en el observable del servicio en el componente) **para que constantemente este verificando y actualizando la información de la BD y refrescando el MaterialDataTable.** Muchas Gracias.

El código:

[Modelo]

```
export interface PaisesItem {
    idPaises?:number;
    pais:string;
    nacionalidad:string;
}
```

[Servicio]

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public listar():Observable<PaisesItem[]>{
    return this.http.get<PaisesItem[]>(this.RUTA_API+'/paises');
  }
}
```

[ts]

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.paisesService.listar().subscribe((row: PaisesItem[])=>{
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(row);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
  }
```

[html]

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
  
      <!-- ID Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="idPaises">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.idPaises}} </td>
      </ng-container>
...
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

Comment: Es que no veo manera de que tu observable se entere que hicieron una inserción manual desde la base de datos, otra sería que cada cierto tiempo vuelvas a llamar el  this.listar pero mmmmmmm sería muy puerco y mucho para el servidor.

Comment: pero ah como dices si lo haces desde la tabla, por ejemplo en la función donde agregas un nuevo registro, puedes hacer un subject que cada vez que se registre algo detone un next() y luego ya en el ts, te suscribes a ese subject y cada vez que se denote algo, vuelves a llamar el this.listar y así estarias reaccionando a nuevas insertaciones

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias, respecto a llamar el this cada cierto tiempo estaba pensando si hubiese manera de ir consultando si hubo cambios en la BD cada cierto tiempo, de haber csmbios debera traer la información. No se si esto es demasiado para el servidor pero pense que angular lo hacia de manera nativa, en fin.

Comment: Respecto a la sugerencia de agregar registro, en definitiva se debe hacer lo que comentas para actualizar la tabla, pero en si la pregunta por ahora se limita a como hacer para que la informacion que se lista en la MaterialTableDataSource se mantenga actualizada automaticamente sin refrescar pantalla. Es decir si yo hago un cambio obviamente se debe reflejar en la tabla pero que pasa si otra persona hace un cambio desde otra parte, la idea es que pueda ver dicha informacion actualizada sin necesidad de refrescar la pantalla.  Si me pueden ayudar en esto les agradezco soy nuevo en angular.

Comment: con un socket es la forma que se me ocurre